# I can't understand _chipmunk_cffi.lib cp

Tags: pymunk

When I trace to `_chipmunk_cffi.py`, it is from `pymunk._chipmunk_cffi_abi import ffi, lib, lib_path`.

So I trace to `_chipmunk_cffi_abi.py` and it's only `lib, lib_path = load_library(ffi, "chipmunk", debug_lib=_lib_debug)` but I can't find `ffi` anymore. So what is that?

I want to see what is doing in `space.step()`, where can I find this?

Answer (score 0):

Pymunk is not doing the actual simulation itself, but is using a separate c library called Chipmunk for that part. Chipmunk is written in C, and called from the Python code in Pymunk with the CFFI foreign function interface library. I dont think you can trace it directly from the Python side into C-code. Instead if you want to see what it is looking like you can check the c-source directly, for example the step function is here: https://github.com/viblo/pymunk/blob/0d79176cf2fd642bd2ce4005478cb8d6e37c1e9c/chipmunk_src/src/cpSpaceStep.c#L336